# Why does nslookup for espn.com give an IP that goes to go.com?

Tags: dns, ip, http

If I do an nslookup on `espn.com`, an `IP` is returned `199.181.132.250`. When I put this value in the browser I get `go.com`.

If I had add a '`Host` header to the request, I still end up on `go.com`.

What am I not grasping?

**Update**

What I'm not understanding is... if I go to apple.com and open the Chrome Developer Tools and look at the network tab for the resource request, an `IP` is present. If I take that `IP` with a `Host` header of apple.com and use the Chrome tool `Postman` to send a request to said `IP`, I do not get apple.com returned. I get some garbage page. Why is this?

Comment: Because ESPN is a Disney property.

Comment: Apple and Disney have their webservers configured differently

Answer (score 2):

Multiple A-records are allowed in the direct DNS-zone. But only one PTR-record is recommended in the reverse zone. That is why lot of hostnames can be resolved to the single IP, while each IP in general is  resolved to the one hostname.

All that primarily intended for `name-based virtual hosts`.

Comment: So an `HTTP` request without a `Host` header would go to go.com but if I add a host header of espn.com, I'd get there? Is this correct?

Comment: All queries goes to the same IP, but software on it decide how exactly they should be processed. Most http-servers can recognize the `host` header and behave correspondingly. In general there is so-called `default virtual server` that is used in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

They seem to have a HTTP redirect in there.

Why do you care?

**UPDATE** Oh you asked for the IP. Well they're probably using [Name-based Virtual Hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based) on that IP.